# Google Static Maps API access with key doesn't get logged in reports

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I'm using Google Static Maps API with an API key from the APIs console.

when I go to 'reports' I see 0 requests for the Static Maps API.
for the Google Places API I can see stats as expected.

does anyone else experience that? maybe the stats for this API take long time to update ?

Comment: There isn't a programming issue here. This sort of problem should be reported and discussed on the Google Group. Since this explicitly refers to Console keys, the Version 3 Group is *probably* right: http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/

Comment: is it the right group to report even if i'm not using the js-api ?

Comment: Far better than here, because SO is *only* for programming queries.

Comment: Actually, there is a group for the Google Maps web services: https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api-web-services?pli=1